# How to convert forEach values into an array and store in a constant with Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach

How do I convert my forEach values into an array and store it in a constant with Javascript?

This is my code:

```
  const today = new Date();
  const twoDaysAgo = subDays(today, 2);
  const sevenDaysAgo = subDays(today, 6);

  const sevenDays = eachDayOfInterval({ start: sevenDaysAgo, end: twoDaysAgo });

  sevenDays.forEach((day) => {
    const arr = format(day, 'eeee', { locale: nl });
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  });
```

So I am able to use a const `myArray` like myArray.map((item) => //etc....`

Comment: Yeah, just use map instead of forEach, map returns a new array

Comment: `const arr = sevenDays.map(day => format(day, 'eeee', { locale: nl }))`